# How to update a column status in another table from previous query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2014. The query that I run results 2 columns, one is ID and another is Ticket number.

Now on another table which is `DW-STG` there are columns `ID`, `Ticketnumber` and `cancel_YN`.

What I want to do is to update the status of a `cancel_YN` column to `Y` for those ticket numbers which were returned by the query that I ran earlier which is returning `ID` and `Ticketnumber`.

Below is the query code which outputs ID and Ticketnumber.

```
select 
    STG2_SBR_PNR_HEADER.HID, DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH.Ticketnumber
from 
    STG2_SBR_PNR_HEADER
join
    DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH on STG2_SBR_PNR_HEADER.HID = DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH.HID

except

select 
    STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH.HID, STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH.Ticketnumber 
from 
    STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH
```

Sample of data returned by query:

```
ID     Ticketnumber
-------------------
1      123
2      456
```

Desired result in DW_STG table:

```
ID    Ticket    Cancel_YN
---------------------------------------------------
1     123         Y (previously by default it is N)
2     456         Y (previously by default it is N)
3     745         N
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that query in a CTE.
Then in the update, join the table to the unique ticket numbers in it.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT fafh.Ticketnumber, fafh.HID
   FROM DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH fafh
   JOIN STG2_SBR_PNR_HEADER head ON head.HID = fafh.HID

   EXCEPT

   SELECT Ticketnumber, HID
   FROM STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH
)
UPDATE t
SET cancel_YN = 'Y'
FROM DW-STG t
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Ticketnumber FROM CTE) q
  ON q.Ticketnumber = t.Ticketnumber;
```

Comment: this answer is more easy to understand and completes my requirement. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the query you posted gives the result you want, you can use it in your update statement
 with the only difference that it must return only the column `DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH.Ticketnumber`:

```
update DW-STG
set cancel_YN = 'y'
where Ticketnumber IN (
  select DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH.Ticketnumber
  from STG2_SBR_PNR_HEADER
  JOIN DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH ON STG2_SBR_PNR_HEADER.HID=DW_SBR_FARES_FAFH.HID
  except
  select STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH.HID,STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH.Ticketnumber from 
  STG2_SBR_FARES_FAFH
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). See following sample:

```
DECLARE @DWSTG TABLE (
    ID int,
    Ticketnumber int,
    cancel_YN char(1)
);

INSERT @DWSTG VALUES
(1,10,'N'),
(2,20,'N'),
(3,30,'N'),
(4,40,'N');

MERGE @DWSTG Dest
USING (
    --here comes your query
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (2, 20), (3,30)) T(ID, TicketNumber)
) Src
ON Dest.ID=Src.ID AND Dest.TicketNumber = Src.TicketNumber
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET cancel_YN = 'Y';

SELECT * FROM @DWSTG;
```

Result:

```
ID          Ticketnumber cancel_YN
----------- ------------ ---------
1           10           N
2           20           Y
3           30           Y
4           40           N
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `inner join` in the following way.

```
create table firstResult (ID int, Ticketnumber int)
insert into firstResult values (1, 123), (2, 456)

create table secondResult (ID int, Ticketnumber int, Cancel_YN char(1) default 'N')
insert into secondResult (Id, TicketNumber) values(1, 123),(2, 456),(3,745)

update s 
set s.Cancel_YN = 'Y'
from firstResult as f
inner join secondResult s on s.Ticketnumber = f.TicketNumber

select * from secondResult
```

Here I have assumed `firstResult` is the table of first query output and `secondResult` table is for second query output.
You can replace both table name with actual query in bracket `()`.